# nasm x86: 64-bit division always results in 1

Tags: assembly, x86

Noob to ASM so probably a stupid mistake, but I can't seem to find a solution anywhere.
I'm trying to divide EDX:EAX by EBX and display the quotient, but whenever I run it i always get 1 in the EAX register no matter the numbers (as long as they're positive).

```
    SYS_EXIT equ 1
    SYS_READ equ 3
    SYS_WRITE equ 4
    STD_IN equ 0
    STD_OUT equ 1

section .data
    msg1 db 'Enter first number:', 0xA, 0xD
    len1 equ $ - msg1
    msg2 db 'Enter divisor:', 0xA, 0xD
    len2 equ $ - msg2
    msg3 db 'Result: '
    len3 equ $ - msg3
    msg4 db ' ', 0xA, 0xD
    len4 equ $ - msg4

section .bss
    num1 resb 2
    num2 resb 2
    res resb 2

section .text
    global _start

_start:
mov eax, SYS_WRITE
mov ebx, STD_OUT
mov ecx, msg1
mov edx, len1
int 0x80

mov eax, SYS_READ
mov ebx, STD_IN
mov ecx, num1
mov edx, 2
int 0x80

mov eax, SYS_WRITE
mov ebx, STD_OUT
mov ecx, msg2
mov edx, len2
int 0x80

mov eax, SYS_READ
mov ebx, STD_IN
mov ecx, num2
mov edx, 2
int 0x80

mov eax, SYS_WRITE
mov ebx, STD_OUT
mov ecx, msg3
mov edx, len3
int 0x80

xor edx, edx
mov eax, [num1]
cdq
mov ebx, [num2]
div ebx
add eax, byte 48
mov [res], eax
int 0x80

mov eax, SYS_WRITE
mov ebx, STD_OUT
mov ecx, res
mov edx, 2
int 0x80

mov eax, SYS_WRITE
mov ebx, STD_OUT
mov ecx, msg4
mov edx, len4
int 0x80

mov eax, SYS_EXIT
int 0x80
```

Comment: You forgot to convert your input from text to number. Also, you are loading 4 bytes from a space of 2 bytes only.

Comment: As in sub '0' from eax and ebx before division?

Comment: And where am I loading the 2 extra bytes? Sorry, I'm very new to ASM

Comment: `mov eax, [num1]` - loading a dword, so both `num1` and `num2` concatenated.

Comment: So change eax to ax and so on during calculations?

Comment: Good thought but it won't help much. The big problem here is that you've read a string from STD_IN but you're not parsing the string, you're reinterpreting it as an integer, which Jester also mentioned in the first comment.

Comment: Should subtracting 48 bytes from the strings before the div opcode work?

Comment: For single digits, yes. You should then load a single byte though.

Comment: By loading a single byte do you mean dividing w/ ax/bl registers or appending another byte to the string or something entirely different?

Comment: Whichever is convenient. Simplest is probably to use zero extension, e.g. `movzx eax, byte [num1]` or similar.

Comment: The "string" in assembly read by `SYS_READ` `int 0x80` is sequence of byte values encoded according to ASCII encoding (i.e. a font glyph 0 has value `'0' == 48 == 0x30`). If user enters `123`, you receive two byte values `'1'` and `'2'` (`'3'` is lost because `edx=2`). If user enters `5`, you receive two byte values `'5'` and `10` (line feed). Try watch the memory in debugger, and try to enter different strings and different arguments, to get better grasp how it works and what are your input data. (Then to get integer value `12` from string `"12"` means `('1'-'0')*10 + ('2'-'0')`).

Comment: And that conversion is usually done by a loop, which multiplies temporary sum (initialized to 0) by 10, then adds value of next digit to it (integer value of next ASCII digit is the ascii code minus ascii code of 0, that's that sub `'0'`). And you watch for the end of string (either LF character, or running to the end of buffer .. if you add fixed LF after the input buffer, you can safely check only for LF without checking length). There's ton of these questions here on stackoverflow, you may also want to search tag x86 info: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info

Comment: Uh oh, and to output the result you have of course to do the opposite conversion, from numeric integer value binary encoded in the 32 bits of `eax` to the string, the `add eax,48` will work only for single digit results, if the result is for example 17, then 17+48 = 65, and that's the capital letter `'A'` in the ASCII encoding. If you are just starting with asm, it may be better to postpone the string manipulation, and focus first on integer arithmetic, inputting values through source (+recompile and run) and check results through debugger, stepping over single instructions.